# Php url rewrite in routed index

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been searching this site for days and tried everything to resolve my problem but it still exists. I have coded my own cms and now i need to rewrite all urls .Specific problem is that i have one point access trough index.php like `index.php?go=users&task=add_friend` now i'm trying to rewrite url to just have `/users/add_friend` and similar but always get homepage with no css styling and javascript. My last try to get it right

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d



RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$  index.php?go=profile&id=$1   [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?go=profile&id=$1   [QSA,L]`
```

txn in advance

Comment: rewrite conditions only get applied to the immediately following rule. So your second rule has no conditions

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this maybe?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

# passthrough anything that maps to a file/dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?go=profile&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?go=$1&task=$2 [QSA,L]
```

As for your css/js problem, your links are probably all relative links, and when you have additional depth in your URL (more `/`'s) your relative URL base changes and any of your relative links will be broken. You can either make them all absolute links or add a relative URL base in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: This works for all my site options but not for profile than i've found something that works fine for all <code>RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^index.php$  index.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^users/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  index.php?go=profile&id=$1 [NC,QSA]</code>

Comment: don't know how to format thic code in comment ,sorry . first time looking for help here

Answer (score 0):

That's because once you do the rewrite you need to either

use the `BASE` tag in the head section.

```
<base href="/">
```

or use the full path to your CSS and JS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/full/path/to/style.css">
```

Then your css and JS will show up.

Also you don't need 2 rules just to make the `/` optional. You can do this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?go=profile&id=$1   [QSA,L]
```